# Error message when executing Insert Into query in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a query where I am looking to take data from one table and insert that into another table if specific criteria are met -

the first table (Temp_Day_Table) has columns:  Emp_ID_FK, Time_ID_FK, Hours, Description, Day - it is not indexed and has no key - it's essentially a temporary table where all data will be deleted after the insert into query has executed.

the second table (EMP_TIME) is has the columns:  EMP_ID_FK, TIME_ID_FK, Hours, Date_Time, EMP_TIME_DESC.  The primary key is comprised of EMP_ID_FK, TIME_ID_FK, and Date_Time.

The intention of the query is to insert all values from Temp_Day_Table into EMP_TIME if there is a value in 'Hours' and the values for the primary key do not already exist.

The query seems to work as expected, however when it's executed, I get a pop-up error message that reads as follows:

> Employee Time can't append all the records in the append query.
>
> Employee time set 0 field(s) to Null due to a type conversion failure, and it didn't add 4 record(s) to the table due to key violations, 0 record(s) due to lock violations, and 0 record(s) due to validation rule violations.
>
> Do you want to run the action query anyway?

Specifically it indicates that the query didn't add (#) records to the table due to key violations - the error message gives the option to ignore the errors and run the query anyways, and when doing this, the query executes as expected and doesn't produce any duplicates in the end table (EMP_TIME) - I don't understand why I'm getting the key violation if the query is not attempting to insert a primary key duplicate.  It is attempting to insert duplicates of parts of the primary key (ie EMP_ID_FK) but not the entire key - I'm sure I'm missing something as I'm still early in my sql & access adventure but just looking to resolve the error.

here is the query being executed:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_TIME ( EMP_ID_FK, TIME_ID_FK, Hours, Date_Time, EMP_TIME_Desc )
SELECT t.Emp_ID_FK, t.Time_ID_FK, t.Hours, t.Day, t.Description
FROM Temp_Day_Table t

left join EMP_TIME on t.EMP_ID_FK = EMP_TIME.EMP_ID_FK
and t.Time_ID_FK = EMP_TIME.TIME_ID_FK
and t.Day = EMP_TIME.Date_Time

where t.Hours <> 0;
```

Again, the query seems to operate as expected, but Access is throwing a key violation error and I'm not sure exactly why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get what you want if you change the WHERE clause to this? `WHERE t.Hours <> 0 AND EMP_TIME.EMP_ID_FK Is Null`

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Bohemian - Sorry - I have updated the post

Comment: @HansUp - That seems to work thanks - but why?  Clearly I've got some more learning to do.

Comment: Open a copy of the original query in the query designer and switch to SQL View.  Discard the INSERT line.  Then change the SELECT line to just `SELECT *`  If you then run that altered query I think you will see 4 rows where the EMP_TIME EMP_ID_FK, TIME_ID_FK, and Date_Time columns have values (are not Null).  That is because EMP_TIME already contains rows with those combinations of values --- so you don't want to add them again.  Including the condition `EMP_TIME.EMP_ID_FK Is Null` to the `WHERE` clause tells the db engine to exlcude those rows from the data it attempts to add to EMP_TIME.

Comment: When doing as suggested, there are 4 rows from the Temp_Day_Table that have values, but the EMP_TIME table returns null values - there is only a value in the EMP_TIME table return columns if that table has data already that contains those combinations of values, but I was getting an error message even when there was no data in the EMP_TIME table that contained matching combinations with the original query.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp - while I don't fully understand it yet, the visual aid did help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the two criteria by using `NOT EXISTS` for the key check:

```
INSERT INTO EMP_TIME ( EMP_ID_FK, TIME_ID_FK, Hours, Date_Time, EMP_TIME_Desc )
SELECT t.Emp_ID_FK, t.Time_ID_FK, t.Hours, t.Day, t.Description
FROM Temp_Day_Table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM EMP_TIME x
  WHERE t.EMP_ID_FK = x.EMP_ID_FK
  AND t.Time_ID_FK = x.TIME_ID_FK
  AND t.Day = x.Date_Time
)
AND t.Hours <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you - could you explain why this does not throw an error while the join does?  Is it because the joins are compared individually but the 'not exist' is comparing the entire record? - also, this answer is much more complex than what HansUp suggested above though both seem to have the same results - is there a benefit to your suggestion over that of HansUp?

Comment: @AFish the benefit is readability - it's a direct translation of your requirements from English to SQL. The optimizer will probably convert it to a join when executed anyway. Maintainability and readability are high priorities when writing code.